# How to add registration information to my page in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to the username to a view.
My devise model is: Player

For example:

```
Welcome [Username] to the website.
```

I am using Rails 4, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view/layout add following:

```
Welcome <%= current_player.username %> to the website.
```